# Нужно ли ставить запятую после или перед "и"?

Tags: пунктуация

Также нужно запастись свободным временем, желанием, хорошим настроением и, самое главное терпением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Также нужно запастись свободным временем, желанием, хорошим настроением и, самое главное, терпением.**

Самое главное ―  вводное слово, оно обособляется запятыми.

В данном случае союз И является замыкающим в ряде однородных дополнений, **это соединительный союз.**

Считать его присоединительным и ставить перед ним запятую нет смысла.

Пример:

Её ужаснула бедность, грязь и, **главное**, трудность ежедневной жизни... [Людмила Улицкая.  // «Новый Мир», 2000]